# Angular/ionic : Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I tried to implement fullcalendar (4.1.0) library in my angular 5.0.0 / ionic (v4, i'm using scss too). In fullcalendar docs it says that i have to import these 2 css files in my global css stylesheet:

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

But for some reason, the css doesn't load and the project gives me the following error:

> Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
> checking is enabled.

I tried a lot of things, but none of them worked for me and now im kinda confused and don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: Why version 4.1? That is a long way out of date. Use the latest version and see if you still have any problems.

Comment: Because the latest version is not compatible with angular version 5.0.0

Comment: Are you using Fullcalendar's Angular component in your site? It isn't entirely clear. According to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/angular it only supports Angular 7. Angular 5 is so far out of date I would guess you'll find it difficult to get support for many things really.

Comment: Yes and i'm not having any problem with it, i have this:
    <full-calendar #fullcalendar [plugins]="options.plugins"></full-calendar>
Indeed, it displays correctly, the problem comes when the css has to be applied, it drops that weird error.

Comment: `i'm not having any problem with it`...except the problem you're having

Comment: It's really weird because i tried it with another library that also needs to insert the css via import in the global css, but that one works fine...

Comment: Just something I've observed: `Refused to apply style from ''` ...the name of the source is missing. Are you sure it's actually loading anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, my project was built with SASS and i just discovered that the imports for .css files needs to end without it. Just like This:

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main';
```